# How to manually retrieve a pending Firebase Dynamic Link when FirebaseDeepLinkAutomaticRetrievalEnabled is set to NO

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've set `FirebaseDeepLinkAutomaticRetrievalEnabled` to `NO` in the Info.plist of my app because I want to be in control of when exactly during app launch the existence of a pending link is checked. (If I don't add this key, Firebase will call the App Delegate's openUrl method.)

In the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Sources/FIRDynamicLinks.m#L133) of Firebase Dynamic Links I was able to find that if I disable automatic retrieval, I should "call strong match FDL API to retrieve a pending link":

```objectivec
// Check for pending Dynamic Link automatically if enabled, otherwise we expect the developer to
// call strong match FDL API to retrieve a pending link.
if ([FIRDynamicLinks isAutomaticRetrievalEnabled]) {
  [dynamicLinks checkForPendingDynamicLink];
}
```

What API are they referring to? I checked the API docs & source code but can't find anything that is declared public for me to call.